# Loading functions into excel

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I'm trying to generate some excel files by creating a csv file and then loading it into excel. All is going well except the formulas, so for example if my csv file is something like '1, 2, =SUM(A1:B1)' then my formula just shows up as plain text when I import the CSV into excel.

Only way it works is by clicking on the cell first and then by clicking in the formula box. But this is a pain to do when you generate large files. Is there any work around? Also, I noticed that the cell is set to general, it's not even set to text.

An alternative solution would be nice too, I haven't tested it on google docs or libreoffice yet. But excel is preferred.

Comment: Can you please show some representative CSV rows, that indicate where values are specified and where formulas are needed (and the syntax). Just expand on the existing example data. The reason being how to handle the current row number (if you import not under the first row) and what if formula references the row above.

Comment: A quick workaround is to open the CSV in another sheet and only copy over the values only (if they are in separate columns), maintaining the existing formulas.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, you can do the following.

```
Sub FixFormulas()
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Formula = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2
End Sub
```

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I want to load my formula from csv format into excel.

Comment: If you load the .csv in to Excel, then run this macro and it will fix the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rolling your own CSV file reader, that handles the `=..` cells differently

```
Public Sub ImportCSV(ByVal path As String, ByRef r_target As Range)

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(path)
    
    Dim line As String, parts() As String, item As String
    Dim j As Long, n As Long, row As Long
    row = 1
    Do Until ts.AtEndOfStream
        line = ts.ReadLine()
        parts = Split(line, ",")
        n = UBound(parts)
        For j = 0 To n
            item = Trim(parts(j))
            If Left$(item, 1) = "=" Then
                r_target.Cells(row, j + 1).Formula = item
            ElseIf Left$(item, 1) = "'" Then
                r_target.Cells(row, j + 1).Value = item
            Else
                r_target.Cells(row, j + 1).Value = Evaluate(item)
            End If
        Next j
        row = row + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

The above requires a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in order to access a `FileSystemObject` for file manipulation.

[image: scr1]

This is the test data I used

```
1,2,=A1+B1,=2*A1-B1
2,4,=A2+B2,=2*A2-B2
3,3,=A3+B3,=2*A3-B3
```

and this is the code I run

```
Call ImportCSV("C:\Temp\data.csv", Sheet1.Range("A1"))
```

and the expected✔ results

[image: scr2]